# Shaping Div with Sloping Edge While Keeping PHP Generated Background

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a site here:

http://www.jasnasyogaonline.com/membership-test.php

And if you hover over the right nav, you'll see a fade in effect that happens where the background animates to the top and bottom from the middle of the link. In between the three colored lines (the border of the right nav) you'll see that there is white color. This is because on the other pages of the site, the background is white and the original programmer just used a background image to create the 'diagonal' edge of the nav item. Now that there is a full page video/image, this doesn't work because the background isn't white and the effect is lost.

My client is now looking to just have it be transparent between the razor lines but keep the nav items with the diagonal edges. If I removed the images on the end of the nav item, they just become straight rectangles. I've tried some CSS with borders/border-widths, etc. but it's a little tricky because if you look at the source code, the background is being generated by a PHP file that's using imagecreatetruecolor to create the hover effect.

Any ideas on how to cut the corner off of the right nav while keep the area between the razor lines transparent? I'm beginning to run out of ideas. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to drop the hover edge div all together

```
  .nav ul li div {
```

The recode the animation using a background sprite / animation.  In reality I don't really like the mouse over effect at all.  Maybe you could sell the customer on something that is easier to do like a text outer glow or an underlining effect.

Also: this post doesn't have anything to do with PHP

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I would agree with you, it may even be possible to recreate the effect in jQuery? The only reason I tagged 'PHP' is because the background on the page is being generated by a PHP imagecreatetruecolor so it kind of ties in with the functionality...

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT** I can't think of another way this can be achieved but you can try if you want this design.

```
.nav ul li a:hover {
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
-moz-border-radius: 10em 0em 10em 0em;
border-radius: 10em 0em 10em 0em;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: **EDIT** Use this editted image instead of `.../hover-edge.png`

[link](http://s22.postimg.org/4fd0c0a6l/hover_edge.png)

Comment: That's not going to work. It will still show the blue behind it because it's transparent and the right nav will still show the rectangle in full. The rectangle needs to be 'cut off' somehow.